# Possible to trigger action depending on given params for MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Say I have a controller called User, and I have a Index `ActionResult`, and then a secondary `ActionResult` called SetUserInfo. Example below:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var enviorment = Zen.Components.Environment.GetEnvironmentByID(id);

        return View(settingsViewModal);
    }


    //Second action
     public ActionResult SetSite(int id, int siteID)
    {
        var enviorment =
          Zen.Components.Environment.GetEnvironmentByID(
             new EnviornmentQuery() {EnviormentID = id, SiteID = siteID);

        return View(enviorment.Site);
     }
```

Since the url "Settings?id=1" fires the ActionResult "Index", can I get "Settings?id=1&siteID=133" to then let the controller know it has to trigger ActionResult "SetSite" based on the params it was given, or do I have to make them optional in the first ActionResult, OR am I thinking of this all wrong. The route mapping is what is taking me a minute to fully get. I know it can be called as follows "Settings/SetSite?id=1&siteID=133", but wondering if I can do my prior example? If so, is it a bad way to handle it, or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map a route for it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SetSiteRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{siteID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "SetSite" }
    //                                  Important part ^^^^^^^
);
```

Make sure you put it above your default route so that it takes precedence (routes are processed in order).

This will allow: `www.site.com/Settings/1/500` where 1 is the `id`, and 500 is the `siteID`.

Comment: Just a quick comment you might want to add the next route for the settings route directly under so the route table is complete. Just providing the one route wont work. As the OP request is on the `User` controller not the `Settings` controller. Your first route should be `.. defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "SetSite" }` then add the next route below without the siteID portion as the index route `/Settings` doesnt follow the `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Just a thought for completeness. Cheers

Comment: OP said "I know it can be called as follows Settings/SetSite?id=1&siteID=133". That looks like `Settings` is the controller.. can the OP clarify?

Comment: Fair enough.. I guess its interpretation. Good answer! :)

Comment: in case of `www.site.com/1/500`, I think it will route to `SetSite`.. and what in case of `www.site.com/`?.. I think it should be `url: "Settings/{action}/{id}/{siteID}",` as @Nico has mentioned in his answer..

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly the answer you may be looking for..

First off, you cant map your route that way. The route cannot contain the ? character, so although you could use an alternative way to call your route using something like

```
/Settings/{id}/{siteId}
```

Using the following

```
/Settings?id={id}&siteID={siteId}
```

Cant be mapped as a route. However you could easily add the site id property to your Index action such as.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, int? siteID)
{
    if (siteID.HasValue)
        return SetSite(id, siteID);
    return null;
}


//Second action
public ActionResult SetSite(int id, int siteID)
{
    return null;
}
```

I know this isnt exactly what you are looking for but will achieve the same result without having to mess around with your routes and urls. (Note i am just returning null so it compiles).

Cheers.

Comment: Yea, I mentioned in my question I was wanting another way besides that. The problem is that this view contains a page to configure settings. On the page, there are a group of settings for the sites of the environment. So, when the initial load of the view is called, it loads the environment. Then if they select a site to configure, I didn't want to have a redundancy in action methods, with a tiny difference in logic just to get a site id from it.  Thanks thoguh. Maybe I just have to use the optional param, and then some if logic in my index action.

Comment: @Casey if you really want to seperate the logic through routes I suggest using the /Settings/{id}/{siteID} format as this is a true way to seperate the routes.

Comment: I thank you for the answer, but this is what I was trying to avoid as mentioned again. Thanks again though.

Comment: Also, I think I am misunderstanding the flow of the idea behind this. Say I have a View, that handles an Environment object. Now I have a partial view within that view, that renders sites that belong to the Environments object. Do I use a completely separate controller, even though they are on the same page, or do I use the same controller, and different methods "ActioNResults"? Basically, do you always only have a controller per page, but many views that are handled by it?